# Combobox with custom picker collapses randomly

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/363k) combo with a custom picker that collapses when:

First scenario:
Combobox collapses on toolbar click.
Clicking anywhere on the toolbar, beside the button - this worked fine in the previous version of ExtJs 6.2.0.589

Second scenario:
Combobox collapses on tooltip click.
Expand combobox picker and click 'Show tooltip' button, then click 'do NOT collapse combo on click' checkbox or anywhere inside the tooltip.

[image]

Help is much appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting issue. I am pretty sure it has to do something with a change in Component Manager global focus handling, but I could not isolate it. To solve this, personally I would use a custom window instead of a picker.